# Training with RMSPROP gives different results

Tags: optimization, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm training a neural network (a CNN on top of an RNN), using theano, and using RMSPROP for optimisation (I'm using lasagne implementation for that).
My problem is, every time I train the network, I get totally different results (accuracies). I'm initializing the parameters using a fixed seed and the problem doesn't happen when I train with SGD, so I guess RMSPROP is what causes the problem.

Is this a normal behaviour with RMSPROP? What is the best practice to deal with that? Should I train the network several times and take the best model?

I'm also optimising using one example per time (my training set is small so I'm not using mini-batches or batches) is this a good practice with RMSPROP?

Answer (score 0):

Usually batch sizes around 40 gives better results, as for my experience training with 40 batch size for 3 epocs using default RMsprop gives around 89% accuracy. Have you tried adjusting the learning rate of RMsprop optimizer ? try with a very small value first ( default is 0.001, in keras implementation) and try to increment it with factors of 10 or 100.